# Как сделать счетчик (калькулятор), сколько сотрудников уволилось? Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

В программе учета сотрудников, можно добавлять сотрудников и удалять.
Но я не знаю как связать удаление сотрудников и калькулятор, надеюсь поможете) Удаление происходит через DELETE FROM staff WHERE id=?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3


# Класс Main
class Main(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.init_main()
        self.db = db
        self.view_records()

# Главное окно
    def init_main(self):
        toolbar = tk.Frame(bg='beige', bd=2)
        toolbar.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)

        self.add_img = tk.PhotoImage(file='add.png')
        btn_open_dialog = tk.Button(toolbar, text='Добавить сотрудника ', command=self.open_dialog, bg='beige',
                                    bd=0, compound=tk.TOP, image=self.add_img)
        btn_open_dialog.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        self.update_img = tk.PhotoImage(file='edit.png')
        btn_edit_dialog = tk.Button(toolbar, text='Редактировать', bg='beige', bd=0, image=self.update_img,
                                    compound=tk.TOP, command=self.open_update_dialog)
        btn_edit_dialog.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        self.delete_img = tk.PhotoImage(file='delete.png')
        btn_delete_dialog = tk.Button(toolbar, text='Удалить', bg='beige', bd=0, image=self.delete_img,
                                      compound=tk.TOP, command=self.delete_records)
        btn_delete_dialog.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        self.search_img = tk.PhotoImage(file='search.png')
        btn_search = tk.Button(toolbar, text='Поиск', bg='beige', bd=0, image=self.search_img,
                               compound=tk.TOP, command=self.open_search_dialog)

        btn_search.pack(side=tk.LEFT)


        self.refresh_img = tk.PhotoImage(file='refresh.png')
        btn_refresh = tk.Button(toolbar, text='Обновить', bg='beige', bd=0, image=self.refresh_img,
                                compound=tk.TOP, command=self.view_records)
        btn_refresh.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        
        
        

        
        
        

        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self, columns=('ID', 'employee', 'position', 'salary'), height=15, show='headings')

        self.tree.column('ID', width=30, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column('employee', width=365, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column('position', width=150, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column('salary', width=100, anchor=tk.CENTER)

        self.tree.heading('ID', text='ID')
        self.tree.heading('employee', text='Сотрудник')
        self.tree.heading('position', text='Должность')
        self.tree.heading('salary', text='Зарплата')

        self.tree.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        scroll = tk.Scrollbar(self, command=self.tree.yview)
        scroll.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.Y)
        self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)

# Добавление данных
    def records(self, employee, position, salary):
        self.db.insert_data(employee, position, salary)
        self.view_records()

# Обновление данных
    def update_record(self, employee, position, salary):
        self.db.c.execute('''UPDATE staff SET employee=?, position=?, salary=? WHERE ID=?''',
                          (employee, position, salary, self.tree.set(self.tree.selection()[0], '#1')))
        self.db.conn.commit()
        self.view_records()

# Вывод данных
    def view_records(self):
        self.db.c.execute('''SELECT * FROM staff''')
        [self.tree.delete(i) for i in self.tree.get_children()]
        [self.tree.insert('', 'end', values=row) for row in self.db.c.fetchall()]

# Удаление данных
    def delete_records(self):
        for selection_item in self.tree.selection():
            self.db.c.execute('''DELETE FROM staff WHERE id=? ''', (self.tree.set(selection_item, '#1'),))
            self.db.conn.commit()
            self.view_records()





# Поиск данных
    def search_records(self, employee):
        employee = ('%' + employee + '%',)
        self.db.c.execute('''SELECT * FROM staff WHERE employee LIKE ?''', employee)
        [self.tree.delete(i) for i in self.tree.get_children()]
        [self.tree.insert('', 'end', values=row) for row in self.db.c.fetchall()]

# Открытие дочернего окна
    def open_dialog(self):
        Child()

    def open_update_dialog(self):
        Update()

    def open_search_dialog(self):
        Search()




# Дочернее окно
class Child(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.init_child()
        self.view = app

    def init_child(self):
        self.title('Добавить сотрудника')
        self.geometry('400x220+400+300')
        self.resizable(False, False)

        label_employee = tk.Label(self, text='Сотрудник')
        label_employee.place(x=50, y=50)

        label_select = tk.Label(self, text='Должность')
        label_select.place(x=50, y=80)

        label_salary = tk.Label(self, text='Зарплата ')
        label_salary.place(x=50, y=110)

        self.entry_employee = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_employee.place(x=200, y=50)

        self.combobox = ttk.Combobox(self, values=[u'Менеджер', u'Бухгалтер', u'Юрист'])
        self.combobox.current(0)
        self.combobox.place(x=200, y=80)

        self.entry_money = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_money.place(x=200, y=110)



        btn_cancel = ttk.Button(self, text='Закрыть', command=self.destroy)
        btn_cancel.place(x=300, y=150)

        self.btn_ok = ttk.Button(self, text='Добавить')
        self.btn_ok.place(x=220, y=150)
        self.btn_ok.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: self.view.records(self.entry_employee.get(),
                                                                       self.combobox.get(),
                                                                       self.entry_money.get()))

        self.grab_set()
        self.focus_set()


# Класс обновления унаследованный от дочернего окна
class Update(Child):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_edit()
        self.view = app
        self.db = db
        self.default_data()


    def init_edit(self):
        self.title('Редактировать сотрудников')
        btn_edit = ttk.Button(self, text='Редактировать')
        btn_edit.place(x=205, y=150)
        btn_edit.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: self.view.update_record(self.entry_employee.get(),
                                                                          self.combobox.get(),
                                                                          self.entry_money.get()))
        self.btn_ok.destroy()


    def default_data(self):
        self.db.c.execute('''SELECT * FROM staff WHERE id=?''',
                          (self.view.tree.set(self.view.tree.selection()[0], '#1'),))
        row = self.db.c.fetchone()
        self.entry_employee.insert(0, row[1])
        if row[2] != 'Менеджер':
            self.combobox.current(1)
        self.entry_money.insert(0, row[3])


# Поиск по наименованию
class Search(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_search()
        self.view = app

    def init_search(self):
        self.title('Поиск')
        self.geometry('300x100+400+300')
        self.resizable(False, False)

        label_search = tk.Label(self, text='Поиск')
        label_search.place(x=50, y=20)

        self.entry_search = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_search.place(x=105, y=20, width=150)

        btn_cancel = ttk.Button(self, text='Закрыть', command=self.destroy)
        btn_cancel.place(x=185, y=50)

        btn_search = ttk.Button(self, text='Поиск')
        btn_search.place(x=105, y=50)
        btn_search.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: self.view.search_records(self.entry_search.get()))
        btn_search.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: self.destroy(), add='+')


# Создание базы данных
class DB:
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect('staff.db')
        self.c = self.conn.cursor()
        self.c.execute(
            '''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS staff (id integer primary key, employee text, 
            position text, salary real)''')
        self.conn.commit()

    def insert_data(self, employee, position, salary):
        self.c.execute('''INSERT INTO staff (employee, position, salary) VALUES (?, ?, ?) ''',
                       (employee, position, salary))
        self.conn.commit()


# Основной код для запуска
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    db = DB()
    app = Main(root)
    app.pack()
    root.title("Staff")
    root.geometry("665x450+300+200")
    root.resizable(False, False)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: сотрудников обычно не удаляют, просто помечают статусом, что он уволился. Что касается вашей задачи, то пишите события найма\удаления в отдельную таблицу, по ней и стройте отчеты.

Answer (score 0):

Для реализации счетчика уволившихся сотрудников вам нужно внести следующие изменения в код:

Создайте новое поле в таблице сотрудников, которое будет отражать статус сотрудника (например, "уволен").
Обновите метод delete_records в классе Main, чтобы помечать сотрудников как уволенных, а не удалять их полностью из базы данных. Например, вы можете установить значение столбца "статус" для выбранных сотрудников равным "уволен".
Создайте новый метод count_dismissed_employees в классе Main, который будет подсчитывать количество уволенных сотрудников.
Создайте новую метку (label) в главном окне (Main.init_main), которая будет отображать количество уволенных сотрудников.
Обновляйте значение метки при добавлении и удалении сотрудников.

Ниже приведен обновленный код с внесенными изменениями:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3


class Main(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.init_main()
        self.db = db
        self.view_records()

    def init_main(self):
        # ... existing code ...

        # Метка для отображения количества уволенных сотрудников
        self.dismissed_label = tk.Label(toolbar, text='Уволено: 0')
        self.dismissed_label.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

    def records(self, employee, position, salary):
        self.db.insert_data(employee, position, salary)
        self.view_records()

    def update_record(self, employee, position, salary):
        # ... existing code ...

    def view_records(self):
        # ... existing code ...

    def delete_records(self):
        dismissed_count = 0  # Счетчик уволенных сотрудников
        for selection_item in self.tree.selection():
            employee_id = self.tree.set(selection_item, '#1')
            self.db.c.execute('''UPDATE staff SET status=? WHERE id=? ''', ('уволен', employee_id))
            self.db.conn.commit()
            dismissed_count += 1
        self.view_records()

        self.dismissed_label.configure(text=f'Уволено: {dismissed_count}')

    def count_dismissed_employees(self):
        self.db.c.execute('''SELECT COUNT(*) FROM staff WHERE status=?''', ('уволен',))
        count = self.db.c.fetchone()[0]
        return count


class Child(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        # ... existing code ...

        self.btn_ok.bind('<Button-1>', self.add_employee_and_update_dismissed_count)

    def add_employee_and_update_dismissed_count(self, event):
        self.view.records(self.entry_employee.get(), self.combobox.get(), self.entry_money.get())
        dismissed_count = self.view.count_dismissed_employees()
        self.view.dismissed_label.configure(text=f'Уволено: {dismissed_count}')
class Update(Child):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_edit()
        self.view = app
        self.db = db
        self.default_data()

    def init_edit(self):
        # ... existing code ...

    def default_data(self):
        # ... existing code ...
class Update(Child):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_edit()
        self.view = app
        self.db = db
        self.default_data()

    def init_edit(self):
        # ... existing code ...

    def default_data(self):
        # ... existing code ...
```

Продолжайте обновлять остальные части кода, добавляя необходимые изменения, как описано выше. Это включает метод search_records, класс Search и другие части кода, связанные с функциональностью добавления, обновления и удаления сотрудников.

Обратите внимание, что вам также понадобится обновить создание таблицы staff в базе данных, чтобы добавить новый столбец status:

python

```
self.c.execute(
    '''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS staff (id integer primary key, employee text, 
    position text, salary real, status text)''')
```

Эти изменения должны помочь вам связать удаление сотрудников и подсчет количества уволенных сотрудников.